# Saving results to file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

My program is supposed to execute received sample code, and then save the results back into new file. When the result of executed sample code is a number, it works, but when it's a string, it won't save result into file (it creates new file, but its content is empty).

How to make it to save all types?

```
class ExecuteProgram

  # opens recieved code and saves it to a variable
  @code = File.open("files/prog.rb", "r"){ |file| file.read }

  # executes recieved code
  @number = eval(@code)

  # saves result to file
  def self.save_code(filename="result.rb")
    directory_name = "result"
    Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)
    file = File.new(directory_name + "/" + filename, "w")
    file.puts(@number)
    file.close
    puts @number
  end

  ExecuteProgram.save_code("result.rb")

end
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't look like it should have a problem with strings. Could you also share the code that fails to produce the string?

Comment: Nah, can't be that strings cause that problem here.

Comment: The aim of  program is to execute any code it will recieve, so I tried to put different code, more complex or simple that returns sum of numbers or string. Example content of prog.rb:
print "Hello World"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the code into a proc with something like:

`@number = eval("Proc.new {#{@code}}")`

Then saving it to the file with `file.puts(@number.call)`

Comment: I added this, but now I'm getting error: "execute_program.rb:7:in `eval': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)"

Comment: I did it different way, without eval and it works :)